# Cast collation of nvarchar variables in t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, collation, string-comparison

I need to change the collation of an nvarchar variable. [By documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx):

> (...) 
>   3. The COLLATE clause can be specified
>   at several levels. These include the
>   following:
>
> Casting the collation of an
>   expression.  You can use the COLLATE
>   clause to apply a character expression
>   to a certain collation. Character
>   literals and variables are assigned
>   the default collation of the current
>   database. Column references are
>   assigned the definition collation of
>   the column. For the collation of an
>   expression, see [Collation Precedence](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql2000/html/tsqlref/ts_da-db_7ory.htm)
>   (Transact-SQL).

However I can't figure out the correct syntax for the usage of CAST(), CONVERT() or variable declaration with DECLARE for this purpose.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST('abc' AS varchar(5)) COLLATE French_CS_AS
```

Comment: This comes from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 23):

`CAST` or `CONVERT` is superfluous!

```
SELECT N'abc' COLLATE French_CS_AS
```

It is superfluous because just changing the collation does not change the data type `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: Got here trying to cast an NVARCHAR to a VARCHAR of a specified collation. (Note the actual characters that can be stored in a VARCHAR vary with the collation.)

Comment: @Joshua perhaps this is the wrong question because it's not about VARCHAR.

Answer (score 5):

If you are changing between 2 and 1 byte, or vice-ver-sa, character encodings then CAST or Convert is necessary. It is not superfluous in these cases.

When the source column is a 2 byte character sequence (nchar, nvarchar) and the selection projection is required to be a single byte character (char, varchar), you should specify the cast and convert. Apply the collation conversion before the casting between the type systems.

```
SELECT CAST(N'ФBC' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as varchar(10)) AS ProjectedSingleByte
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to compare or join two columns of different collation this could help.
In my case I had to compare two columns with one using 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' and the other using  'Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'.

I simply used this option where i join these two.

> on A.Person = B.NAME collate database_default