# Select column, Lower and UpperCase

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table in SQL with a column `Status`. In that column I have some values... like `Ok`, `NOK`, and `ok` with lower case.

How can i select those rows with `OK`  ( uppercase) and `ok` (lowercase)

`Select * from table where status = 'OK'` has the same result with `Select * from table where status = 'ok'`

If I do
`Select * from table where lower(status) = 'ok'` does not help me neither, because `LOWER('OK') = 'ok'` so all rows will be selected

So how can i select only those with ok (lowercase)?

Comment: Please tag which (RM)DB you are using as well

Comment: This query should simple work for you ```Select * from table where status = 'ok';```. Can you elaborate your issue.

Comment: Use a case sensitive collation. (Which will be a product depending choice, and perhaps syntax too.)

Comment: As @jarlh says, if your DB has a case insensitive collation you'll need to cast it as a case sensitive one for the comparison - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1631936/1544886

Comment: However, why do you want to treat `Ok`, `ok` and `OK` as different values? Seems like an odd - _and risky_ - design decision.

Comment: Duplicated as **SQL Server** question?!? How come? @Zerfad, are you using MS SQL Server? (From now on, always add a dbms tag to your SQL questions you ask here.)

Comment: Jim Macaulay, 
Select * from table where status = 'ok' - 500 rows
Select * from table where status = 'OK' -500 rows

In my column i have some rows with "ok" and another rows with "OK". Those 2 statements will return same amount of rows,  i need something to select with case sensitive

Comment: Jarlh, yes i want to threat OK and ok as different values. Yes this was a bad decision and now i need to fix it
I am using SSMS

Comment: @jarlh OP did not tag and there was nothing to indicate which DBMS it was. The principle is the same though: change the collation.

Comment: you can do: `Select * from table where status collate latin1_general_cs_as IN ('OK', 'ok')`. I AM curious what you're gonna do with those rows versus the other ones though... If you are gonna update them, you might as well skip the whole case sensitive thing and update rest of the table as well